# add new attribute from other model to user model

Tags: django, model

I have structure model with id and name_structure and I want when I add user I affect them in one structure like 
username john 
password 1234
structure electric department

but I don't know how can I do this work in Django so please help me?

**this models.py in immob app**

```
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.
class structure(models.Model):
    structure_code=models.CharField(max_length=1)
    structure_desig=models.CharField(max_length=350)
    class service(models.Model):
    structure_id=models.ForeignKey(structure,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=0)
    service_desig=models.CharField(max_length=350)
```

**and this model of complete app (account)**

```
# Create your models here.
from immob.models import structure
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class utilisateur(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    structure=models.ForeignKey(structure,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Pls fix the indentation and remove all those fields that have nothing to do with the question. People might actually try to read your code then ;)

Comment: ok i will do it

Comment: i edited your question. try use triple ` instead quadru-space for box of code.

Answer (score 0):

we thinking that you have all data in a specific view in a view.py or anywhere else, then we can create or get a user plus create or get a structure instance then we can create a new utilisateur instance:

```
from immob.models import Structure
from compte.models import Utilisateur

def adding_utilisateur(request):
   .
   .
   .
   # we assume you have data as we need to create or get a new user/structure
   new_user = User.objects.create_user(userName, userMail, userPass)
   new_user.save() # new user is ready
   new_structure,create = Structure.objects.get_or_create(
                                      structure_code=ValueOfStructerCode,
                                      structure_desig=ValueOfStructtureDesign)
   if create : 
       new_structure.save()  # we have our structure instance too

   # time to create a Utilisateur's instance
   new_utilisateur.objects.create(structure=new_structure, user=new_user)
   new_utilisateur.save() # done!
```

trying to found what you want.

Comment: i want add username and password and  choose structure  in same forms ? how i can do it